# Audio CD's, Data CD's, and DVD's not recognized

Tags: dvd, cd

Some days I boot up, stick an audio CD in the drive, the little light blinks, and the disc shows up in Files, Picard, and Banshee.  Yay!  Other days, I insert a CD, the little light on the drive blinks, then stops and nothing useful happens.  Today is one of those "other days."  With an audio CD in the drive, Eject can't find the CDROM:

```
$ eject
eject: unable to find or open device for: `cdrom'
```

LSHW can't either:

```
$ sudo lshw |grep cdrom
$
$ sudo lshw |grep dvd
$
$ sudo lshw -C disk
$
```

I don't see it in /dev:

```
$ ls /dev/cd*
ls: cannot access '/dev/cd*': No such file or directory
```

Not sure this is relevant:

```
$ ls -1 /dev/disk/by-id/
nvme-Samsung_SSD_950_PRO_512GB_S2GMNXAH209808D
nvme-Samsung_SSD_950_PRO_512GB_S2GMNXAH209808D-part1
nvme-Samsung_SSD_950_PRO_512GB_S2GMNXAH209808D-part2
nvme-Samsung_SSD_950_PRO_512GB_S2GMNXAH209808D-part3
nvme-Samsung_SSD_950_PRO_512GB_S2GMNXAH209808D-part4
```

I just tried sticking a couple of different data disks in the drive and the light flashed, but they didn't show up anywhere, just like the audio CD.

## Reboot 1

I shut down, opened the case, and plugged the CD/DVD drive into a different SATA port (1 instead of 0).  Same issue.

## Reboot 2

I shut down, plugged the CD/DVD drive back into the original SATA port (0), wiggled both ends of the SATA cable to be absolutely certain they were seating properly (they appeared to be), and booted into the BIOS.  I made a totally inconsequential change (turned on the CPU heat alarm) saved BIOS settings, booted ***AND IT WORKED!***

## System

Ubuntu 16.04, 64-bit.  My only hard drive is the Samsung 950 pro NVME which is mounted in a PCIe adapter (it's sweet).  My CD/DVD drive is a TSTcorp CDDVD ATAPI and it's the only drive connected through SATA.  My motherboard is a GA-Z97X-UD3H-BK rev-1.0.

Comment: Did you check inside the system that all cables are firmly connected ? Could be a hardware problem.

Comment: @JonasCz I think you're right.  See my new update, "Reboot 2" above.  If you make this comment into an answer, I'll up-vote and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same/similar problem here. Opening the case and replugging the SCSI / power cables has worked to get CDROM working - for the moment - it will invariably stop working in a few hours/days; now I at times lose a HD once the CDROM is back in operation.

My guess is that this may be a POWER problem - i.e., power supply may be too weak to run 3 HDs, CDROM (former configuration which worked) and the new graphics card (CDROM stopped working shortly thereafter but never paid much attention as I hardly use of late).

Comment: It's nice using an OS where when you have real trouble fixing a problem, it turns out to be hardware!  Yours could be power.  Mine's worked great since I twiddled the plugs.

Comment: Guess the problem can be tagged as "solved"?